# Allowing user to input number of threads and based on the number of threads distribute additions to each thread

Tags: java

Im trying to create a program whereby users can enter a range of numbers for eg: 1 and then 10, so 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 will be added, but not directly, they can be separated into threads. So user can input the number of threads, for eg: if its 5 threads, thread 1 will perform 1+2, thread 2 performs 3+4 , thread 3 and so on. Each thread will then add together to come up with a total.

I have done the part where the addition works but im not sure how to separate it into the number of user input threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow keep the index of elements printed to console already, so it could be done by sending a parameter to the `run()` function which starts from the first element and keeps on to the second thread.

try the following implementation of the code changes:

```
for (int i=0; i<threadNo; i++) 
    {  
       MultithreadingSum object = new 
       MultithreadingSum(start,end,threadNo,noOfDigits);
       object.run(i*(end/threadNo)); //sending a parameter to run()
    }


public void run(int time) //time variable to start each time run() is called from current place
    {   
       int total =0;
       System.out.println("Thread executed");
       for(a = i + time; a <= j/n+time ; a++){
           System.out.print(a +" ");
           total+=a;
       }
       System.out.println(getName() + " is "+ total);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome i got exactly what i wanted.
1+2+
Thread-0 total sum is 3
Thread executed
3+4+
Thread-1 total sum is 7
Thread executed
5+6+
Thread-2 total sum is 11
How do i add the total sum of each thread to make a grand total? for eg 3+7+11 , do i return the value?

Comment: You could switch the `void run()` to `int run()` and return the total

Comment: possible, I can't think of any other ways at the moment, but since there is no limit to the thread count an array is not the best choice

Comment: Hey sir could you explain why u passed this parameter (i*(end/threadNo)) to run();

Comment: `(end/threadNo)` is the portion/amount between thread to thread, and `i*` is going to set the starting point each time from the current place